# Blazor Radio Button State Handle on Exception

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, radio-button, state

I am developing an application in Microsoft Blazor using .NET 7 and I have a razor component with a radio button with three state like the following:

```
<div class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
    <input type="radio" name="stg_linkage_state" id="stg_linkage_off" value="off" checked="@(is_linked_stg == -1 ? true: false)" @onclick="async (eventArgs) => { await ChangeLinkageSTGGroup(mapping, group, false); }" />
    <label for="stg_linkage_off" onclick="">OFF</label>
    <input type="radio" name="stg_linkage_state" id="stg_linkage_na" value="na" checked="@(is_linked_stg == 0 ? true: false)" disabled />
    <label for="stg_linkage_na" onclick="">N/A</label>
    <input type="radio" name="stg_linkage_state" id="stg_linkage_on" value="on" checked="@(is_linked_stg == +1 ? true: false)" @onclick="async (eventArgs) => { await ChangeLinkageSTGGroup(mapping, group, true); }" />
    <label for="stg_linkage_on" onclick="">ON</label>
</div>
```

And here is the onclick method:

```
protected async Task ChangeLinkageSTGGroup(VirtualMapping_CL_Sub mapping, VirtualGroup group, bool IsLinked)
{
    var response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/mapping_cl/linkage_stg/change", communication);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //IF RESPONSE IS OK CHANGE THE STATUS
        //OK
    }
    else
    {
        //IF RESPONSE IS NOT OK CHANGE DO NOT CHANGE THE STATUS
        is_linked_stg = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<int>("/api/mapping_cl/linkage_stg/view/" + group.group_id + "/" + "-1", Parameters.jsonSerializerOptions);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        await ShowTheExceptionModal(responseContent);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Notice that when a failure is occurred the code goes to "else" and a new integer will be assigned based on another method. I have check that on failure the method returns proper code but the radio button state does not change to the assigned value. I have the feeling that this is happening because the status assignment from user click is assigned after the method assign the proper integer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As your code doesn't constitute a *Minimal Reproducible Example*, I've created one based on your code that I believe replicates your code.  I may be wrong!

I've refactored the markup and the code. `CheckValidStateAsync` is the equivalent to your `ChangeLinkageSTGGroup`.

This works - See the comments.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
    <input type="radio" name="@_uniqueName" checked="@this.IsSelected(-1)" @onchange="() => ChangeState(-1)" />
    <label>OFF</label>
    <input type="radio" name="@_uniqueName" checked="@this.IsSelected(0)" @onchange="() => ChangeState(0)" disabled />
    <label>N/A</label>
    <input type="radio" name="@_uniqueName" checked="@this.IsSelected(1)" @onchange="() => ChangeState(1)" />
    <label>ON</label>
    <input type="radio" name="@_uniqueName" checked="@this.IsSelected(100)" @onchange="() => ChangeState(100)" />
    <label>Not Allowed</label>
</div>

@code {
    private int _state;
    private string _uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    private bool IsSelected(int value)
        => value == _state;

    private async Task ChangeState(int value)
    {
        // need to set to a not allowed number 
        // so we cover the situation where we change it 
        // for example from -1 back to -1 
        _state = int.MinValue;
        var checkedValue = await this.CheckValidStateAsync(value);
        _state = checkedValue;
    }

    private async ValueTask<int> CheckValidStateAsync(int value)
    {
        // Fake an async operation
        await Task.Delay(500);

        if (value > 1)
            return -1;

        return value;
    }
}
```